# Openstack Auto-Pilot - No Hardware Zones / Physical Zones Listed in Landsacape

Tags: openstack, ubuntu

Following the instructions available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

I am at the final step of the landscape / autopilot install. The pre-configure checklist shows everything is good, but when I click configure there is no hardware listed for me to add to physical zones.

**[Landscap Openstack Tab](http://d.pr/i/1gjlj)**

**[Landscap Openstack Tab](http://d.pr/i/Oizj)**

**Network tab in MAAS** - Each node is attached to Internet and one of the BladeNet networks

```
Name            Desc                    Network                    Gateway          Nodes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BladeNet1       BladeNet1-10.0.1.0      10.0.1.0/24                10.0.1.1         4
BladeNet2       BladeNet2-10.0.2.0      10.0.2.0/24                10.0.2.1         4
BladeNet3       BladeNet3-10.0.3.0      10.0.3.0/24                10.0.3.1         4
BladeNet4       BladeNet4-10.0.4.0      10.0.4.0/24                10.0.4.1         1
Internet                                192.168.1.0/24             192.168.1.1      13
```

**Zones Tab in MAAS** - Each node is assigned to a Zone

```
Name            Description                     Nodes
-----------------------------------------------------
BladeGroup1     Bay 1, Bay 2, Bay 9, Bay 10     4
BladeGroup2     Bay 3, Bay 4, Bay 11, Bay 12    4
BladeGroup3     Bay 5, Bay 6, Bay 13, Bay 14    4
BladeGroup4     Bay 7, Bay 8, Bay 15, Bay 16    1
default         0
```

**Nodes tab in MAAS** - Each node has 2 drives (146GB HP Logical) & 2 NICs

```
FQDN                            Status      Owner       Cores   RAM (GiB)   Disk (GB)       MAC                             Zone
runny-rabbits.22u.local         Ready                   16      48          146             3c:4a:92:de:8c:c8 (+1)      BladeGroup3         
murky-end.22u.local             Ready                   16      48          146             3c:4a:92:de:87:e0 (+1)      BladeGroup3             
medical-jam.22u.local           Ready                   16      8           146             3c:4a:92:de:66:a8 (+1)      BladeGroup3             
studious-deer.22u.local         Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:1c:60 (+1)      BladeGroup2             
skeletal-floor.22u.local        Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:f6:30 (+1)      BladeGroup2             
short-monkey.22u.local          Ready                   16      8           146             3c:4a:92:de:fb:80 (+1)      BladeGroup3             
wordy-bucket.22u.local          Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:46:d0 (+1)      BladeGroup2             
shady-cent.22u.local            Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:57:f0 (+1)      BladeGroup2             
exotic-apparel.22u.local        Ready                   16      48          146             3c:4a:92:dd:db:80 (+1)      BladeGroup4             
considerate-trick.22u.local     Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:c6:90 (+1)      BladeGroup1             
cavernous-cannon.22u.local      Deployed    openstack   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:16:f0 (+1)      BladeGroup              
likely-doctor.22u.local         Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:57:30 (+1)      BladeGroup1             
disguised-ornament.22u.local    Ready                   16      16          146             3c:4a:92:de:3c:10 (+1)      BladeGroup1
```